# C++ concurrent priority queue memory leak

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-leaks, priority-queue

I am programming a multithreaded program filling/reading a concurrent priority queue in C++ using Intel TBB, when printing successive popped elements I observed a memory leak. This does not happen if not printing them to the terminal or using a single thread to fill and pop the queue. I have no idea where that could come from, could anyone help please ?

NB: the same thing happened when using STL queue or priority_queue

Intel TBB concurrent priority queue documentation :
https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_priority_queue_cls.htm

I have written a small example similar to my program to demonstrate my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>

#include "tbb/concurrent_priority_queue.h"

typedef tbb::concurrent_priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<int>> EventQueue;

void Fill(EventQueue* _queue,uint64_t N)
{
    for (uint64_t i=0; i<N; ++i)
        _queue->emplace(new int{1});
}

void Read(EventQueue* _queue,uint64_t N) 
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> currentEvent;
    uint64_t count=0;
    while (count<=N) {       
        if (!_queue->empty()) {
            bool test = _queue->try_pop(currentEvent);       
            std::cout << *currentEvent.get() << std::endl; 
            ++count;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    EventQueue eventQueue;

    uint64_t N = 1e10;

    std::thread fill_thread(Fill,&eventQueue,N);
    std::thread read_thread(Read,&eventQueue,N);

    fill_thread.join();
    read_thread.join();
}
```

I am using large integer values as I am working on databases of billions of lines, it seems that large N values causes the leak as when using a smaller N like 1000000 no memory leak happens, to be honest I do not really need the print to the terminal during the multi-thread but seeing that happening I was curious to know the reason.

Comment: Guess, new throws if too large for int? Try make_shared

Comment: 1e10 * (sizeof(value_type) + sizeof(reference_counter) + sizeof(pointer)) > 100MB on 32 bit system. You need to limit the max number of items in queue or use other means to throttle the producer (Fill).

Comment: out of interest, what evidence do you have of a memory leak?

Comment: I concur with Quentin, using compressed pairs via `make_shared` is a much better idea, as it can reduce the allocations (and thus fragmentation) by 50%. And though completely unrelated, firing up two threads here is overkill. After firing up the (Read) thread you can just *call* `Fill(&eventQueue, N);`, then join the reader. May as well use the thread in `main()` you're already running.

Comment: I work under Ubuntu and run in the terminal the command "watch -n 1 cat /proc/meminfo" to check my memory usage and my available memory is decreasing quickly when running this code

Comment: Quentin, indeed new throws a bad_alloc exception and even using make_shared, however its use has decreased the memory leak but yet still there...thanks for notifying make_shared I was actually never using it but in my case it can be better indeed